# How to set scale_x_log10(FALSE/TRUE) by checkbox in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

The following code does not work. What do I have to change?

Specific:
I want the X-Axis to change to logaritmic scale when a checkbox is ticked.

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
...
checkboxInput("logarithmicX", "show x-axis in log10", FALSE),
checkboxInput("logarithmicY", "show y-axis in log10", FALSE),
...
))
```

---

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
...
xlog <- reactive({
 switch(input$logarithmicX,
        TRUE == TRUE,
        FALSE == FALSE)
})
ylog <- reactive({
 switch(input$logarithmicY,
        TRUE == TRUE,
        FALSE == FALSE)
})

ggplot(datasetInput(), aes(size)) + geom_histogram(bins = biins) + theme_bw() + scale_x_log10("logarithmicX") +scale_y_log10("logarithmicY")
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
  mygg <- ggplot(datasetInput(), aes(size)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = biins) +
    theme_bw()

  if(input$logarithmicX)
    mygg <- mygg + scale_x_log10()

  if(input$logarithmicY)
    mygg <- mygg + scale_y_log10()

  return(mygg)
})
```

---

**Edit:** working example.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

runApp(
  shinyApp(
    ui = {
      pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327254'),
        sidebarPanel(
          checkboxInput("logarithmicX", "show x-axis in log10", FALSE),
          checkboxInput("logarithmicY", "show y-axis in log10", FALSE)
        ),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput('distPlot')
        )
      )
    },
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        mygg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
          geom_histogram()

        if(input$logarithmicX)
          mygg <- mygg + scale_x_log10()

        if(input$logarithmicY)
          mygg <- mygg + scale_y_log10()

        return(mygg)
      })

    }
  )
)
```